Sampling with replacement, odds of being selected twice. Why is my solution wrong?
I'm going through Blitzstein intro prob and one of the questions is:
A survey is being conducted in a city with 1 million residents. It would be far too expensive to survey all of the residents, so a random sample of size 1000 is chosen he survey is conducted by choosing people one at a time, with replacement and with equal probabilities.
(a) Find the probability that at least one person will get chosen more than once
This problem has been answered before here but I don't quite follow the solution and I'm wondering if someone could help me understand why my solution/approach is incorrect.
My approach: each time, a resident is surveyed there are $10^6$ residents to choose from. Thus the total number of ways this can be done 1,000 times is $(10^6)^{1,000}$ this will be our denominator.
Next, I thought the complement to no one being selected twice is that the 1,000 participants are unique. Which I thought we could approach by doing ${10^6\choose 10^3}$. It appears this part is wrong
So then I simply did $1$ - $\frac{10^6\choose 10^3}{(10^6)^{1,000}}$
My answer is not correct, the answer given in the solutions manual related the problem to the birthday problem, which is an analogy I'm struggling to connect. What I'm trying to understand, why is my approach incorrect?
I understand that for the first person, to have totally unique choices, you have $10^6$ choices, and for the second you have $(10^6 -1)$ choices, for the third $10^6 -2$... $(10^6 -n+1)$ for the $nth$ person, and that's how our numerator should be formed. But I suppose I'm struggling to square that with what I originally had

Note that when using the choose function, the order of candidates selected is not important. But in the denominator, when you use $(10^6)^{1000}$, it is counted as though the order of people selected matters.

@Nic. I see, this is an area of combinatorics I always struggle with. So say we have a subset of n unique individuals, my denominator counts those n individuals n! times right because each arrangement of them is treated as a unique count? I just want to make sure I understand what you're saying.

Addendum added to respond to the comment question of Jackson.

The comment of Nic makes a good point.  You are attempting to express the probability as
$$1 - \frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = (10^6)^{1000}.$$
Personally, I regard your choice of $~D~$ as very convenient, so I will stick with that.  However, this implies that your enumeration of $~N~$ must also regard the order that people were selected as relevant.
You only made one mistake in the analysis in your posted question.
Since $~N~$ must also be enumerated such that order of selection is relevant, once the $~1000~$ people are selected, which can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{10^6}{10^3}~$ ways, you have to consider that the $~1000~$ people can be ordered in $~(1000)!~$ ways.
Therefore,
$$N = \left[ ~\binom{10^6}{10^3} \times (10^3)! ~\right]. \tag1 $$
You can see that the expression in (1) above is consistent with
$$\left[ ~(10^3) \times (10^3 - 1) \times (10^3 - 2) \times \cdots \times (10^3 - 999) ~\right].$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

Ah I need to take order into account on the numerator because I did it on the denom. So an implication from your answer, is that the denominator could have been divided by (1000!)
and that also would have worked? But does that imply that 10^6^1000 divided by 1000! gives me all the unique ways you can select 1,000 people from a group of people with replacement?


...that doesn't make sense to me.

First of all, this is an outstanding question.
The whole point of construing order to be important is that it greatly simplifies the computation of $~D = [ ~10^6 ~]^{1000}.~$  The alternate approach of construing that order is irrelevant in the computation of $~N~$ is no problem: you simply have $~N = \displaystyle \binom{10^6}{10^3}.~$
However, the computation of $~D,~$ when order is regarded as irrelevant is extremely problematic.
To see why, assume (instead) that you have $~4~$ people, instead of $~10^6~$ people, and that you are choosing $~2~$ people instead of $~10^3~$ people.
So, construing order to be important,  the corresponding values of $~N~$ and $~D~$ would be
$$N = \binom{4}{2} \times 2! = 12, ~D = 4^2 \implies \frac{N}{D} = \frac{12}{16} = \frac{3}{4}.$$
Now, if order is not important, then you have
$$N = \binom{4}{2} = 6.$$
From this, you can deduce that if order is not important, that
$$D = \frac{4^2}{2} = 8.$$
However, how can the computation of $~D = 8~$ actually be derived?
Of the $~16~$ selections, $~12~$ of them will involve $~2~$ people, and $~4~$ of them will involve $~1~$ person.
Further, any selection of $~2~$ people is twice as likely to occur as a selection of $~1~$ person.
That is, there are two ways to select (for example) Person-1+Person-2, because they can occur in any order, and only one way to select Person-1+Person-1.
Note that the entire foundation of the $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ approach is that all of the events represented by $~D~$ are equally likely to occur.
So, when computing $~D~$ in the revised problem, with order construed to be irrelevant, the corresponding computation is
$$\binom{4}{2} + \frac{4}{2} = 8.$$
That is, with $~N~$ specified as $~\displaystyle\binom{4}{2},~$ each event like Person-1+Person-2 is assigned 1 unit, and the computation of $~N~$ contains $~6~$ units.
Then, since the $~4~$ events like Person-1+Person-1 are only (1/2) as likely, each such event should be assigned (1/2) of a unit.
So, with $~N~$ now having $~6~$ units, $~D~$ now has $~8~$ units.

When the number of people is $~10^6~$ and the number to be selected is $~10^3,~$ the situation is extraordinarily more complicated than the $~[ ~4 ~\text{people} ~: ~2 ~\text{people} ~]~$ situation.
For $~i \in \Bbb{Z} ~: ~1 \leq i \leq 1000000,~$ let $~x_i~$ denote the number of times that Person-i was selected.
Then, to compute $~N~$ and $~D,~$ where order of selection is regarded as not relevant, you would have to examine each individual solution to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{1000000} = 10^3.$

$x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_{1000000} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
By Stars and Bars theory, the total number of solutions is
$$\binom{ ~10^3 + [ ~10^6 - 1] ~}{ ~10^3 ~}. \tag2 $$
Consider what a specific solution represents.  When order of selection is regarded as relevant, of the $~[10^6]^{1000}~$ equally likely ways of selecting $~1000~$ people, a specific solution will represent
$$\binom{10^3}{x_1} \times \binom{10^3 - x_1}{x_2 } \times \cdots \times \binom{x_{1000000}}{x_{1000000}}$$
$$= (10^3)! \div \left[ ~\prod_{i=1}^{10^6} x_i! ~\right] ~\text{equally likely ways} ~: ~0! = 1. \tag3 $$
This is because there are $~\displaystyle \binom{10^3}{x_1}~$ ways of determining in which of the $~1000~$ positions,
Person-1 could have been selected.  Then, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{10^3 - x_1}{x_2}~$ ways of determining which positions Person-2 could have been selected, and so forth.
Clearly, the scalar in (3) above will vary as each solution varies.  So, when construing that order of selection is not relevant, to compute $~D,~$ you have to apply the scalar in (3) above to each pertinent solution.
This preserves the idea that each element in the sample space of $~D~$ is equally likely.
Then, to compute $~N,~$ you have to apply the scalar in (3) to each of the pertinent solutions.  That is, a solution will be pertinent in the computation of $~N~$ if and only if each of the $~1000000~$ variables $~x_1, \cdots, ~x_{1000000}~$ is either $~1~$ or $~0.~$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10^6}{10^3}~$ such pertinent solutions in the computation of $~N.~$ Then, each such solution would have the scalar of
$$(10^3)! \div \left[ ~(1!)^{1000} \times (0!)^{999000} ~\right] = (10^3)! \div 1 $$
applied.
A moderate refinement is to remove the $~(10^3)!~$ constant in the scalar to be applied, when computing both $~N~$ and $~D.~$  This would then analogize to what actually happened in my discussion of the $~[ ~4 ~\text{people} ~: ~2 ~\text{people} ~]~$ situation.
This (valid) refinement would then result in $~\displaystyle N = \binom{10^6}{10^3},~$ which is consistent with intuition.
All of this is totally impractical to implement when attacking a corresponding math problem.  This is why, in the original problem, it is generally standard to construe order of selection as relevant.

Ah I need to take order into account on the numerator because I did it on the denom. So an implication from your answer, is that the denominator could have been divided by $(1000!)$ and that also would have worked? But does that imply that 10^6^1000 divided by 1000! gives me all the unique ways you can select 1,000 people from a group of people with replacement? Because for some reason that doesn't make sense to me. I understand 1000 people can be arranged in 1000! ways, but what if your group of 1000 people has one person included 10 times?  Don't you need a different division? 990!*10!

@Jackson See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

The real issue is that you can't use the choose function here, because you are not choosing without replacement, you are choosing with replacement, so you must necessarily use permutations
Thus if $n$ is the population, and $k$ the sample size,
P(all people chosen are different) $=\dfrac{^nP_k}{n^k}$
and P(at least one person is chosen more than once) $= 1- \dfrac{^nP_k}{n^k}$
For some obscure reason, the permutation symbol that is taught in high school is not favored on this forum, so instead of using the longer $\binom{n}{k}k!$ for the numerator, you can use Knuth's notation of the falling factorial, if you so prefer, to write
P(at least one person is chosen more than once) $ = 1 - \dfrac{n\frac{k}{~}}{n^k}$

What's the alluded-to beef with $P(n,r)$?

@RobinSparrow: You very rarely see it on MSE, the preferred form seems to be $\binom{n}{r}r!$

I get that empirically we don't see it much - I'm asking is there some reason for that? The "preferred" form seems overwrought and represents two extra (cancelling) steps.

@RobinSparrow: I don't really know, perhaps because the Wikipedia page on permutation has only a cursory mention of the combinations and permutations type.

@trueblueanil I just want to make sure I understand. If I multiply the numerator in my fraction by 1000! I would have had the right answer!?

Yes, you would then get the right answer.

$\binom{a}{b}$ is like a magic tool, and magic tools are reserved for magicians. Magic tools are such that normal people don't understand what happens. I never use those magic tools.
We have a chronology : Select 1 resident, then another resident, then another resident.
We can say : Success is 'at each step, the resident is a new one (not selected before)' ; As soon as I fail, the game ends.
When I select the 1st resident, no problem, I am sure that it is a new one.
When I select the 2nd resident, The probability to loose is $\frac{1}{10^6}$, and the probability to continue the game is $\frac{999999}{10^6}$
When I select the 3rd resident, The probability to loose is $\frac{2}{10^6}$, and the probability to continue the game is $\frac{999998}{10^6}$
Etc
The probability to have $1000$ successes is $\frac{10^6-1}{10^6} \times  \frac{10^6-2}{10^6} \times ... \frac{10^6-999}{10^6}  $
Now, to compute this without repeating too many operations, we can summarize this formula :
$P=\frac{10^6!}{(10^6-1000)! (10^6)^{1000}}$
And the original question was the opposite : We don't want the probability to have a new resident at each step, but the probability to fail at least once :
$P=1-\frac{10^6!}{(10^6-1000)! (10^6)^{1000}}$

I couldn't agree more with your magic and magicians comment. I think one of the reasons I struggle so much with combinatorics is the magic formulas of choose can lead you astray. But sometimes I much prefer counting problems going step by step but that has also massively led me astray, especially when I was doing "poker hands" types of problems. I appreciate your post, I see your logic, although for me it wasn't immediately clear how you simplified the equation, but I think I see it after thinking about it for a while
